# Curl 7.43.0 won't build in MSVC 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, curl

When building libcurl w/ssl from cUrl 7.43.0 in Visual Studio 2013, the following error is reported by the compiler:

1>------ Build started: Project: libcurl, Configuration: DLL Debug - DLL OpenSSL - DLL LibSSH2 Win32 ------
1>  vtls.c
1>C:\Program Files\curlb\curl-7.43.0\curl\lib\urldata.h(86): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/ssl.h': No such file or directory
1>  openssl.c
1>C:\Program Files\curlb\curl-7.43.0\curl\lib\urldata.h(86): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/ssl.h': No such file or directory
1>  darwinssl.c

There is a reference in the Project's Additional Include Directories dialog, that specifies a openssl/inc32 directory.  That directory is not included in build 7.43.0 so far as I can see which may explain why the compiler is complaining.

There seems to be very little information on this error.  I would like to build 7.43.0 as a static library. Is there documentation explaining how to build 7.43.0 in MSVC?  Where can I find these files so cURL can build.

Answer (score 6):

You may just switch configuration to "DLL Debug - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN" (or "LIB Debug - DLL Windows SSPI - DLL WinIDN" to build static library). cURL will be built with Windows SSL library.

OpenSSL is a different library. To build cURL with OpenSSL you should have both of them.